# Got "Access denied for user" when set database memory in laravel test

Tags: laravel, testing

I'm trying to implement testing for my laravel project.

This is my `phpunit.xml` file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="./vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit.xsd"
         bootstrap="vendor/autoload.php"
         colors="true"
>
    <testsuites>
        <testsuite name="Unit">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Unit</directory>
        </testsuite>
        <testsuite name="Feature">
            <directory suffix="Test.php">./tests/Feature</directory>
        </testsuite>
    </testsuites>
    <coverage processUncoveredFiles="true">
        <include>
            <directory suffix=".php">./app</directory>
        </include>
    </coverage>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <server name="APP_KEY" value="base64:in7fPzfWpFUCvr48DCZvkNf5qzqI/6SqSLpJysihepE=" />
        <server name="BCRYPT_ROUNDS" value="4"/>
        <server name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="DB_CONNECTION" value="mysql"/>
        <server name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:"/>
        <server name="MAIL_MAILER" value="array"/>
        <server name="QUEUE_CONNECTION" value="sync"/>
        <server name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <server name="TELESCOPE_ENABLED" value="false"/>
    </php>
</phpunit>
```

And I want to test database connect first, I've used `RefreshDatabase` trait to `AutoRedirectTest` (auto created when I creating project)

```php
<?php

namespace Tests\Feature;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Tests\TestCase;

class AutoRedirectTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /**
     * A basic test example.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function test_home_redirect()
    {
        $response = $this->get('/');
        $response->assertStatus(301);
        $response->assertHeader('Location', '/nova');
    }
}
```

Then when I run `php artisan test`, it throw error when testing `AutoRedirectTest`

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user 'apartment_management'@'%' to database ':memory:' (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = :memory: and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')
```

I've also tried to create new test file and add `RefreshDatabase`. I got the same error. But when I replace `:memory:` to my real database name. I've not got error above anymore.

```xml
<server name="DB_DATABASE" value="my_real_database_name"/>
```

So did I config something wrong?

I'm using laravel 8.61.0 with mysql 5.7.22 configured in docker.

Comment: I thought the memory database was an sqlite only thing

Comment: @apokryfos I've tried to change `DB_CONNECTION` to `sqlite`. The error changed to `SQLite doesn't support dropping foreign keys (you would need to re-create the table).` I think your assumption is correct, I just cannot find document to point it out

Comment: There are a couple of "workarounds" mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/23461), however, I would recommend simply creating a separate MySQL db for testing, especially if this is what you're going to be using in production.